# Incorrect values for large autocad forge drawings

Tags: autodesk-forge

So I was playing around with the autocad forge demos on https://extract.autodesk.io/ and uploaded a few test files.

I noticed that the 3d viewer appears to struggle when rendering objects at large x,y,z values. For a lack of better words, normally straight/curved lines become "squiggly", and jump around wildly. I've done a lot of threejs work, and this happens because you are not moving the original data to some local coordinates.

Here is the original file: 
https://extract.autodesk.io/explore/90377-test2dwg

Here is a more local version that i also uploaded:
https://extract.autodesk.io/explore/84705-testdwg

The strange thing is.. in 2d they are both fine, but in 3d the first one renders very poorly. I was hoping that oViewer.model.getGeometryList().geoms[id].vb would have some local values and i could apply an offset to get the real x,y,z data back, but that doesn't seem to be the case..

Any idea if there is a fix for this coming soon? Is the vertex list in geoms used for rendering, or is it just a copy of the values created at render time? If i can edit some code and change it to a float64array i'd be fine with that.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm checking this and will get back to you

Comment: So i did some poking around in the original lmvworker.js [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/FBX-glTF/), and according to InputStream.prototype.getFloat32/getFloat64, it looks your data buffer is a series of uint8 values being viewed as as a float32 (read 4 bytes) or a float 64 (read 8 bytes).

So i guess this means by the time i am reading the converted file, it is too late to keep full precision?

Comment: have you had a chance to look into this?